# Android listview take much time to load and more memory

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listview` with custom adapter and its working fine. But it takes more than 15 sec to load data to `listview`.and use 60mb of ram memory. Please tell me what is the issue and why its taking too much time? please help me with some code or edit my code .Here is my code. Thanks in advance!
custom adapter

```
public class Listadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    CheckBox checkBox;
    boolean index[];
    boolean[] itemChecked;
    ApplicationInfo entry;
    String[] itempkg;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> mListAppInfo;
    private PackageManager mPackManager;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> checkList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public Listadapter(Context applicationContext, List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplication, PackageManager packageManager)
    {
        //super(applicationContext,textViewResourceId,installedApplication);
        super();
        this.mContext = applicationContext;
        this.mListAppInfo = installedApplication;
        index = new boolean[installedApplication.size()];
        this.mPackManager = packageManager;
        for (int i = 0; i < installedApplication.size(); i++) {
            checkList.add(false);
            itemChecked = new boolean[installedApplication.size()];
            itempkg = new String[installedApplication.size()];
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mListAppInfo.size();
        //return ((null != mListAppInfo) ? mListAppInfo.size() : 0);
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        // index = new boolean[mListAppInfo.size()];
        return mListAppInfo.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // get the selected entry

        final ViewHolder holder;

        //  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getLayoutInflater();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // reference to convertView
            holder.tvAppName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.tvPkgName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.ivAppIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            // holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);

        holder.ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
        holder.tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));
        holder.tvPkgName.setText(entry.packageName);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                    //   SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_APP_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    // SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
                    //  edit.putBoolean("checkbox_" + position, true);
                    //  edit.commit();
                    // editor.putBoolean("CheckBoxState" + position, true);
                } else {
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
                    // editor.putBoolean("CheckBoxState" + position, false);
                    //  SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_APP_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    // SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
                    //  edit.putBoolean("checkbox_" + position, false);
                    // edit.commit();
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
    public void setItemChecked5(boolean[] items5) {
        itemChecked = items5;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView ivAppIcon;
        TextView tvAppName;
        TextView tvPkgName;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

here is activity code

```
public class Profile5Activity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ListView apps5;
        PackageManager packageManager5;
        ArrayList<String> checkedValue5;
        Button bt5;
        ApplicationInfo pi5 = new ApplicationInfo();
        Context context = this;
        static String currentApp5 = "NULL";
        CheckBox cb5;
        Listadapter Adapter5 = null;
        boolean[] itemChecked5;
        //static String currentApp5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile5);
 itemChecked5 = new boolean[AllApps.getInstalledApplication(this).size()];
        //needPermissionForBlocking(MainActivity.mainContext);

        SharedPreferences preferencess2 = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_APP_NAME5", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> seta = preferencess2.getStringSet("pkgname5", null);
        if (seta != null && !seta.isEmpty() && !seta.equals("null")) {
            checkedValue5 = new ArrayList<String>(seta);
        }
        else
        {
            checkedValue5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        // bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        apps5 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewm);
        apps5.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        packageManager5 = getPackageManager();

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        final boolean[] items5 = new boolean[AllApps.getInstalledApplication(this).size()];

        SharedPreferences preferences5 = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_APP_NAME5", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        for (int i = 0; i < AllApps.getInstalledApplication(this).size(); ++i) {
            items5[i] = preferences5.getBoolean("checkbox_5" + i, false);
        }

        Adapter5 = new Listadapter(this, AllApps.getInstalledApplication(this), packageManager5);
        Adapter5.setItemChecked5(items5);
        apps5.setAdapter(Adapter5);
        apps5.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cb5 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        TextView tv5 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        pi5 = (ApplicationInfo) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
        cb5.performClick();

        if (cb5.isChecked()) {
            checkedValue5.add(tv5.getText().toString());
            itemChecked5[position] = true;
            String pname = (tv5.getText().toString());
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "all" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SharedPreferences preferences1 = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_APP_NAME5", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences1.edit();
            Set<String> setttt1 = new HashSet<String>();
            setttt1.addAll(checkedValue5);
            edit.putBoolean("checkbox_5" + position, true);
            edit.putStringSet("pkgname5", setttt1);
            edit.commit();

        } else if (!cb5.isChecked()) {
            checkedValue5.remove(tv5.getText().toString());
            String pname = (tv5.getText().toString());
            SharedPreferences preferences1 = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_APP_NAME5", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences1.edit();
            Set<String> setttt1 = new HashSet<String>();
            setttt1.addAll(checkedValue5);
            edit.putBoolean("checkbox_5" + position, false);
            edit.putStringSet("pkgname5", setttt1);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: try using RecyclerView

Comment: how can use recyclerview will you please edit my code

Comment: how can use recyclerview will you please edit my code @eLemEnt

Comment: Lol....there are plenty of examples available over web for RecyclerView!

Comment: @NosheenCh dude check everywhere you will get lot of example and basic idea of why not to use listview and opt for RecyclerView

Comment: is  entry.loadIcon(mPackManager)  as asynctask?